# Populating the upper triangle portion of a symm matrix using only the lower triangle (in python)?

Tags: python

`H` was taken from a text file and is a lower diagonal matrix which = `[[-1.1422], [-0.997328, -1.1422]]`

Ht is the transpose of `H` which `= [[-1.1422] [-0.997328, -1.1422]]`

I was wondering how I could overlay them in such a way that I get

```
[[-1.1422],[-0.997328], [-0.997328, -1.1422]]
```

In general I would like to populate the upper portion of the symm matrix because the text file only prints the lower half. These are all `NxN` matrices where `N` ranges from `1 - ~25000.`

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
H += H.T # make it symmetric
H -= np.diag(np.diag(H)) # subtract the diagonal which is now double the original
```